# ZMQ Java - Best practice to clean when exiting

Tags: java, zeromq

In ZMQ zguide they [advice](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Making-a-Clean-Exit) to always clean up when task ends. 
I am a bit confused regarding the best practice.

First

- ... even if you close all sockets, zmq_ctx_destroy() will by default wait forever
- ... Finally, destroy the context
- ... This will cause any blocking receives or polls or sends in attached threads to return with an error. Catch that error, and then set linger on, and close sockets in that thread,

**Q1:** So do I need to close all sockets before I destroy the context?

**Q2:** So do I need to destroy the context?

Looking at the **`context.destroy()`** I see it calls linger and close on each socket.

**Q3:** How should I terminate my ZMQ resources?

**EDIT** 
if I look at the  jeromq code - I see inside **`ZContext.destroy`** a call for
`destroySocket` (to each socket ) which

```
s.setLinger( linger );
s.close();
sockets.remove( s );
```

And then it even calls `sockets.clear();` and `context.term();`

**Q4:** Is this enough?

Comment: Why have you asked the same question here and on the zeromq mailing list at the same time. It's not good IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

**A1:** Yes, but ...

**A2:** Yes, but ...

**A3:** Follow the ZeroMQ Best Practice, do not rely just on the language binding

**A4:** Ref. A3

### What is the motivation for "The Best Practice"?

First of all, one shall kindly realise, that ZeroMQ has a certain set of internal architecture  principles that nobody shall either knowingly or accidentally violate.

That said, one may also realise, that different language-bindings ( it is not the ZeroMQ, but some other code-wrapper associated externally with the internal architecture rules ) may have problems on orchestrating gracefull termination ( and some wrappers hide this under the hood so that user is not aware what is going to happen there ).

Endless hanging `.bind()`-s to localhost port(s) and threads caught in dead-locks are just a few troubles one may face with a poor resources release & termination practice.

### What is the ZeroMQ rule of thumb?

1. Enforce a **non-blocking** `.close()` on all ZMQ-socket instances
2. Finally enforce `.term()` the ZMQ-context instance

Ad 1) **non-blocking** means, one **must take due care** of `.setsockopt()` parameters, alike `ZMQ_LINGER`, so as to avoid dead-lock(s) on letting the ZMQ-socket archetype wait endlessly in an expectation, that the opposite counterparty may still have some messages to be received, so be carefull and methodic on this step. Set all safe-exit parameters **before** calling `.close()`. Otherwise you have lost your control entering into a blocking-mode.

Comment: No simple answer to say **"Yes, man, that´s enough."** Albeit it may sound as a Salomon's wisdom, one may only benefit from reading Pieter HINTJEN's book "**Code Connected, Vol. 1**" ( available as PDF ). **Plus** I warmly recommend to anybody, who is planning to do a serious job in distributed systems to also read carefully a post from Martin SUSTRIK ( co-father  of ZeroMQ ) about troubles still entreched in low-level ZeroMQ architecture decissions. **Read** at >>> http://nanomsg.org/documentation-zeromq.html